# Group alphanumerically and include blank fields in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

**I have a dataset, df, that looks like the following:**

My code works well, I would just like to group by numbers, or alpha-numerically instead of LETTERS, because I have a large dataset. I would also like to KEEP the empty subject fields. How can I adjust the code for this? I know I must modify these lines, but am unsure of what to fully do here.

```
mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(new_group)])

filter(Subject != '') %>%








 subject    recipient                  length   folder    message  date                       edit
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM        T                                    
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM        T                   
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        T
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM        F
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM        F 
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        T    
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        T
```

Desired output:

```
 Start                  End                        Duration          Group  Subject  Length
 1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM    1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        29                A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        5                 A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        20                A      hey       80
```

Here is the dput

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"hey", "no", "some"), class = "factor"), Recipient = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("", " ", "a", "k", "sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com"
), class = "factor"), Length = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 
900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, NA, NA
), Folder = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "draft", "in", 
"out"), class = "factor"), Message = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 "jjjjjjj", "llll"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM", 
 "1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM"), class = "factor"), 
 Edit = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
 TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

This is the code I am using:

```
df1<-df %>% 

mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 

mutate_at(c("Subject", "Recipient"), ~if_else(is.na(.), "", stringr::str_trim(.))) %>%
filter(Subject != '') %>%
mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS')) %>%
mutate(cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == '') %>% 
mutate(segment = cumsum(!cond)) %>%
filter(cond) %>%


group_by(Subject, Recipient, Length, segment) %>%
summarize(Start = min(Date),
        End = max(Date),
        Duration = End - Start) %>%


mutate(new_group = (Subject   != lag(Subject, 1, "")) *
       (Recipient != lag(Recipient, 1, "")) *
       (Length    != lag(Length, 1, ""))) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(new_group)])
```

Comment: Hi @Akrun, yes, I believe the segment column was created in the mutate field

Comment: why not just change the last line to `mutate(group = cumsum(new_group))`?

Comment: sorry, it is my mistake

Comment: I will try @GeorgeSavva I was trying to add some alphanumeric. Also, is there a way to keep the blank subject fields? I can remove this: filter(Subject != '') %>% but get some error

Comment: Oh please do not apologize @akrun, do you know of a way to keep the blank subject fields? Also I will try George Suggestion of mutate(group = cumsum(new_group))

Comment: Do you need `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate_at(vars(Subject, Recipient), ~ na_if(str_trim(.), "")) %>% tidyr::fill(Subject, Recipient, .direction = "downup") %>% mutate(cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == '', segment = cumsum(!cond), Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS')) %>% group_by(Subject, Recipient, Length, segment) %>% summarize(Start = min(Date),
        End = max(Date),
        Duration = End - Start) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(newgroup = rleid(Subject, Recipient, Length))`

Comment: let me try thank you @akrun

Comment: @TanishaHudson just a doubt, do you need only the first 3 values

Comment: hi @akrun, what do you mean by first 3 values?

Comment: I meant your desired output only showed the first 3 rows

Comment: oh yes @akrun, because based on the other conditions, it is supposed to filter out the other ones

Comment: It is supposed to show the output based on the conditions of : message == "", Edit = T, folder == out or drafts- it is supposed to group them based on these @akrun, this is what I am trying to figure out how to do